# Geometry: Division of a line segment in a given ratio

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

In geometric construction while dividing a line segment in a given ratio say $m:n$, I have come across the texts that a ray should be drawn making an *acute angle* with the given line segment. I'm not sure why this angle can't be a right angle or an obtuse angle?

Comment: I think you are correct. Any angle will do.

Comment: I can't imagine why this question was downvoted.  It's a perfectly reasonable question, it's about math, and the OP seems to have noticed a flaw in the presentation in his textbook, so you can't say there's no original work here.  Upvoting to compensate.